# Finding the MIN value from the SUM of multiple row grouped by some id

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am using SQLplus connecting to oracle database 12c

I have two tables, Customer and Account, where customers can have multiple accounts (one customer id, but multiple account types). I am trying to get the information on the customer with the largest amount of debt. Suppose we have the following information:

Customer table:

```
BSB#  Customer#  Name  Address
------------------------------
0123  123456     Adam  ABC st
0234  234566     Dave  CBC rd
0345  345667     Max   DSE st
```

Account table:

```
BSB#  Customer#  Type    Balance
---------------------------------
0123  123456     Saving  -2300
0123  123456     Credit  -500
0123  123456     iSaver  200
0234  234566     Saving  5000
0345  345667     Credit  -1500
0345  345667     iSaver  -200
```

The desired output:

```
Customer# Name   Address
-------------------------
123456    Adam   ABC St
```

I can print out the sum of everyone's account balance, but I am not sure how to print out just the information on the account with the lowest accumulated balance. I tried using MIN(SUM(A.Balance)) but I keep getting the error saying "not a single-group function". I wouldn't be surprised if I made a mistake somewhere.

I am relatively new to sql and this is what I have so far. Any advice or pointers would be nice...

```
SELECT C.Customer#, C.Name, Address, SUM(A.Balance)
FROM Customer C
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Account A
ON C.BSB# = A.BSB#
AND
C.Customer# = A.Customer#
GROUP BY C.Customer#, C.Name, Address;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry! I have edited and hopefully, with the help of others, got the right tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will order the customers by the sum of the balances:

```
SELECT C.Customer#, C.Name, Address, SUM(A.Balance)
FROM Customer C JOIN
     Account A
     ON C.BSB# = A.BSB# AND
        C.Customer# = A.Customer#
GROUP BY C.Customer#, C.Name, Address
ORDER BY SUM(A.Balance);
```

If you want only one row, then that depends on the database.  Here are some methods:

Change the `select` to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 . . .
```

Add a `limit` clause to the end of the query:

```
LIMIT 1
```

Add a `fetch` clause to the end of the query:

```
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

And in Oracle, you can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT C.Customer#, C.Name, Address, SUM(A.Balance)
      FROM Customer C JOIN
           Account A
           ON C.BSB# = A.BSB# AND
              C.Customer# = A.Customer#
      GROUP BY C.Customer#, C.Name, Address
      ORDER BY SUM(A.Balance)
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for! I am not sure why I didn't think of using rownum before.

Comment: @Vince . . . Oracle 12 has introduced the `fetch first` clause, so you can also use that (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php).

Comment: Actually i couldn't help but notice the 't' before "WHERE row num = 1". The code seems to run fine without it so i couldn't help but wonder about the significance of the t.

Comment: @Vince . . . That is a table alias and it is optional in Oracle.  In many databases, it is required, so I usually include it by habit.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the folowing statement

```
    with MinAccounts as 
    ( 
      SELECT BSB#, Customer#, Balance
        FROM (
              SELECT BSB#, t.Customer# , sum(t.Balance) Balance, min(sum(t.Balance)) over () minBalance
                FROM Account t
               GROUP BY BSB#, Customer#
         ) d 
   WHERE Balance = minBalance) 
SELECT * 
  FROM MinAccounts a 
  JOIN Customer c ON a.BSB# = c.BSB#
```